# Exporting .jpg files from Data Driven Pages using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, data-driven-pages, jpg

I have generated about 90 maps through data driven pages(ArcGIS 10.0). I now want to export them as .jpg files in either landscape or portrait format.
I tried python but it is not working, it worked to export as.png though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What part of the export from python did not work?  Did it throw an error of some sort?  If you still want to try python and jpg, then it might help to post the code if you think there is a problem with it.  Providing more detail will help you get a better answer.  [How to ask questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: I got it now. There was an error, fixed it.

Comment: What Get Spaial said :) ... Also, Post an answer to your own question mridul.  Since you've sorted it out, others in the community may find your solution helpful with something similar they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I used python code to parse out JPEGs generated from Data driven pages. this method is very useful with one wants to extract multiple maps at once in any format.

Comment: import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"YourMapfilePath")
print mxd.dataDrivenPages.getPageIDFromName("Index Layer name")
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
    row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"Output Path " + row.Index Layer Name + ".jpg")
del mxd

Comment: You should take the comment containing your python code and paste it into an actual answer so that other people searching for a similar problem, will be able to find it.

Comment: This works BUT my jpg file names start with the last folder in the export_path directory. Can this be avoided? Also, why is the del mxd in there? It works without it...

Comment: It is generally considered good practice to delete variables at the end of a script, so they aren't left floating around during that Python instance.  One situation where it might matter is if you use the same variable (e.g. mxd) later in the same script, or in another script in the same Python instance.

Answer (score 16):

I'm simply reposting the code from above as an answer because I found it really useful but it took ages to find:

```
import_path = r"..."   # Path of .mxd
export_path = r"..."   # Path of output file
field_name = "Name" # Name of field used to sort DDP

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path) 
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
   mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
   row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
   print row.getValue(field_name)
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, export_path + "." + row.getValue(field_name) + ".jpg") 
del mxd
```