# Changing output name when exporting data driven pages to JPG?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

Is there a way to save the output JPG, changing the output file name to the page name, instead of page number?

I mean changing the script found in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/exporting-jpg-files-from-data-driven-pages-in-arcmap/144197#144197)?

```
import_path = r"..."   # Path of .mxd
export_path = r"..."   # Path of output file
field_name = "Name" # Name of field used to sort DDP

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path) 
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
   mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
   row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
   print row.getValue(field_name)
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, export_path + "." + row.getValue(field_name) + ".jpg") 
del mxd
```

Comment: Finally I found what I´m was looking for, and made some modification on the scrip to save pdf files, however I get the next error message: AttributeError: Invalid destination path I don't understand where is the mistake

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100949)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100949)

Comment: Victor, i have a script that does exactly the same, but for a PDF format.
contact me, i send it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a new variable: pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Name
You can then include the variable in the export path: str(pageName)

```
import_path = r"..."   # Path of .mxd
export_path = r"..."   # Path of output file
field_name = "Name" # Name of field used to sort DDP

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path) 
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
   mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
   row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow

   pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Name

   print row.getValue(field_name)
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, export_path + "." + row.getValue(field_name) + str(pageName) +".jpg") 
del mxd
```

Comment: Let me know if it works. I didn't test it on my machine.

Comment: Steve, thanks. I saw not your answer, when i was comming here to say that que original script was already saving the way i need. I dont know what happend yestarday, but today is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you define a field name attribute and call it like below: you will be able to use the Page name when exporting to PDF

```
field_name = "***Insert Field Name here****"

page_name = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue(field_name)
str(page_name) + ".pdf")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, ***Path to output folder*** + str(page_name) + ".pdf")
```

That worked for me.