# Python code migration

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, data-driven-pages, map-series

What do I need to change to migrate this ArcMap code to ArcGIS Pro?

It is used
to export hundreds of maps and did its job perfectly.

I got the code from this Q&A:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67520/157904

```
    >>> import_path = r"P:\project.mxd"   # Path of .mxd
export_path = r"P:\"   # Path of output file
field_name = "Taxon" # Name of field used to sort DDP

... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path) 
... for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
...    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
...    row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
...    print row.getValue(field_name)
...    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, export_path + "." + row.getValue(field_name) + ".jpg",resolution=600) 
... del mxd
```

---

This is the error message I get (after @BERAs adaption):

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) In  [3]: Line 5:     ... mxd =
> arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path)
>
> AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'mapping'

Do I have to change **arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path)** with **arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)**?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: where are you migrating to? what seems not to work?

Comment: What is the problem you are having with that code?

Comment: `print row.getValue(field_name)` should be `print(row.getValue(field_name))` since ArcMap is python 2 and ArcGIS Pro p3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To migrate your code from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro, you need to change all references from `arcpy.mapping` to `arcpy.mp`. This is covered in the documentation [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm).
Have a look at the code sample #2 for [MapSeries](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/mapseries-class.htm) for a similar piece of code to your example.